# Proving $\lambda_{\text{min}}\leq R(x)$ without Spectral Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Given a real-symmetric (or Hermitian), positive definite matrix $A$, it is well known that: $$\lambda_{\min}\leq\dfrac{(x,Ax)}{(x,x)}. \tag{1}$$

This is a direct consequence of the min-max theorem  and also easily proved by the fact that such an $A$ has orthonormal eigenbasis. But is there any way to prove this without invoking the Spectral theorem or SVD decomposition or anything that is similarly powerful?

The best I could do was: 
$$\dfrac{(x,Ax)}{(x,x)}\geq \lambda\cdot\dfrac{(x,v)^2}{(v,v)(x,x)} \tag{2}$$
where $\lambda$ and $v$ are an arbitrary eigenpair of $A$, which is weaker than $(1)$ by Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: How about showing that the minimizer of $(Ax,x)$ over the unit sphere $\{x:\|x\|=1\}$ exists (due to the compactness of the unit sphere in the finite-dimensional normed space) and is an eigenvector corresponding to the very minimum? This is a usual variational argument.

Comment: @SangchulLee Though it is a nice argument, if the spectral theorem is considered too powerful, then certainly the use of compactness here is.

Comment: @SvanN we can 'indirectly' appeal to compactness by considering a minimizing sequence (positive-definiteness guarantees a minimum exists) and then using Bolzano-Weierstrauss to extract the convergent subsequence by hand.

Comment: @SangchulLee I like that idea but how does one argue that the minimizer is an eigenvector? Is it by finding the gradient to show the critical points are the eigenvectors and then computing the Hessian?

Comment: I am puzzled by the fact that you want to prove the result for a **symmetric definite matrix** although this result is valid for a **general symmetric matrix**. Do you desire an alternate proof specific to the SDP case ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I see what you are saying and I should say that this is a question that came out of curiosity more than anything. I am relatively a beginner in linear algebra while more experienced in analysis. So I tried to prove the result using only basic real analysis and couldn't. Regarding your comment, I am satisfied with a proof to the SDP case but obviously a proof to the general case without using eigendecomposition is fine as well.

Comment: Here is such a proof (see below). I just finished to write it down when you sent me this comment ;) Definitely, it does not use the fact that $A$ is definite positive.

Comment: Now, I go to sleep (about midnight CET)... Good reading !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m = \inf_{x\ne 0}\frac{\langle Ax,x\rangle}{\|x\|^2} = \inf_{\|x\|=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle$. We claim that $\lambda_{\text{min}} \le m$.

It suffices to show that $m$ is indeed an eigenvalue for $A$.

For that, consider a positive definite matrix $B \ge 0$ and [recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/859328/144766) that $$\|B\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} |\langle Bx,x\rangle| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \langle Bx,x\rangle$$

Pick a sequence $(x_n)_n$ of vectors on the unit sphere such that $\|B\| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \langle Bx_n, x_n\rangle$. We have
$$\|Bx_n - \|B\|x_n\|^2 = \|Bx_n\|^2 + \|B\|^2 - 2\|B\|\langle Bx_n, x_n\rangle \le 2\|B\|(\|B\| - \langle Bx_n, x_n\rangle ) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

so $\lim_{n\to\infty} \|Bx_n - \|B\|x_n\| = 0$. We conclude that $B - \|B\|I$ is not bounded from below so it cannot be invertible. Hence $\|B\|$ is an eigenvalue of $B$.

Now consider $B = \|A\|I - A \ge 0$. We have $$\|B\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \langle Bx,x\rangle = \|A\| - \inf_{\|x\| = 1} \langle Ax,x\rangle = \|A\| - m$$

Above we showed that $\|B\| = \|A\|-m$ is an eigenvalue of $B = \|A\|I - A$ so $m$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

---

In fact, we have $\lambda_{\text{min}}= m$.

To see this, notice that for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ holds $\lambda \ge m$. Indeed, consider $\lambda = m-\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$.

Then for any vector $x$ we have $$\langle (A-\lambda I)x,x\rangle = \langle Ax,x\rangle - \lambda\langle x,x\rangle \ge (m-\lambda)\|x\|^2 = \varepsilon|x\|^2$$

so $$\|(A-\lambda I)x\|\|x\| \ge |\langle (A-\lambda I)x,x\rangle|\ge \varepsilon\|x\|^2$$

Hence $A-\lambda I$ is bounded from below and thus injective. Therefore $\lambda$ cannot be an eigenvalue.

Comment: thanks, this is excellent. So I guess this proof is possible because $A$ is SPD which is what I wanted anyway.

Comment: @dezdichado It is sufficient that $A$ is hermitian (or symmetric). I haven't used $A \ge 0$ anywhere. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/134538/144766) answer claims the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Let} \ \ \ R(X) = \frac{\langle X, AX \rangle}{\langle X, X \rangle},$$

which (by setting $U=X/\|X\|$, i.e. restricting our attention to the unit sphere)is the same as

$$R(U)=\langle U, AU \rangle.$$

There is a classical result

**Proposition** : For any $U$ belonging to the unit sphere, $R(U)$ is a barycenter (normlized weighted mean) *with positive coefficients* of the eigenvalues of $A$.

**Corollary** $R(U)$ is necessary inside the range $[\lambda_{min},\lambda_{max}]$.

As I haven't seen it explained in a simple, non allusive way, I prove it again :

**Proof** : consider an eigendecomposition :

$$A=P^TDP \ \ \text{with} \ \  D=diag(\lambda_1,...\lambda_n)$$

Then : $$R(U)=\langle U, P^TDPU \rangle =\langle \underbrace{PU}_V, DPU \rangle=\langle V, DV \rangle \tag{1}$$

Letting $v_1,v_2,... v_n$ be the coordinates of $V$, (recall that
$v_1^2+v_2^2+...+v_n^2=1$ because $U$ belongs to the unit sphere), we can write :

$$R(U)=v_1\lambda_1v_1+ v_2\lambda_2v_2+\cdots + v_n\lambda_nv_n$$

i.e.,

$$R(U)=v_1^2\lambda_1+ v_2^2\lambda_2+\cdots + v_n^2\lambda_n$$

which is the looked for weighted average of the $\lambda_k$ by positive weights $v_k^2$ whose sum is $1$.