# Lipschitz Hessian implies Lipschitz Hessian diagonal for non-convex function?

Tags: optimization, upper-lower-bounds, lipschitz-functions, non-convex-optimization

I am working on an optimization problem where the function $f$ is assumed to have Lipschitz-continuous gradients and Hessian
\begin{align}
   \| \nabla^2 f(x) - \nabla^2f(y) \| \leq L_1 \| x -y \|, \quad \forall x,y \\
   \| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \| \leq L_2 \| x -y \|, \quad \forall x,y,
\end{align}
but where $\nabla^2 f(x)$ is **not** necessarily positive-semidefinite.

Can we conclude from this that $\text{diag}(\nabla^2 f(x))$ is also Lipschitz (with some other Lipschitz-constant)?

I already found this post [Lipschitz Hessian implies Lipschitz Hessian diagonal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482075/lipschitz-hessian-implies-lipschitz-hessian-diagonal), but it assumes positive-semidefiniteness of $\nabla^2 f(x)$ and I was wondering if we can say something similar without this assumption?

Comment: read the comments there.

Comment: Thanks! When we use the Frobenius norm, it is quite obvious. My question is if the Lipschitz constant can be independent of dimension?

Comment: with the Frobenius norm, every submatrix of the Hessian is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $L_1$. So, is your $L_1$ dimension-dependent or independent?

Comment: Okay, yes I see. Thanks for your answer!